# Perform Fisher Exact Test from aggregated using Stata

Tags: stata

I have a set of data like below:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

They are aggregated data which ABCD constitutes a 2x2 table, and I need to do Fisher exact test on each row, and add a new column for the p-value of the Fisher exact test for that row.

I can use `fisher.exact` and loop to do it in R, but I can't find a command in Stata for Fisher exact test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking in R terms, and that is often fruitless in Stata (just as it is impossible for a Stata guy to figure out how to do `by ... : regress` in R; every package has its own paradigm and its own strengths).

There are no objects to add columns to. May be you could say a little bit more as to what you need to do, eventually, with your p-values, so as to find an appropriate solution that your Stata collaborators would sympathize with.

If you really want to add a new column (`generate` a new variable, speaking Stata), then you might want to look at `tabulate` and its returned values:

```
    clear
    input x y f1 f2
    0 0 5 10
    0 1 7 12
    1 0 3 8
    1 1 9 5
    end
```

I assume that your `A B C D` stand for two binary variables, and the numbers are frequencies in the data. You have to `clear` the memory, as Stata thinks about one data set at a time.

Then you could `tabulate` the results and `generate` new variables containing p-values, although that would be a major waste of memory to create variables that contain a constant value:

```
    tabulate x y [fw=f1], exact
    return list
    generate p1 = r(p_exact)
    tabulate x y [fw=f2], exact
    generate p2 = r(p_exact)
```

Here, `[fw=variable]` is a way to specify frequency weights; I typed `return list` to find out what kind of information Stata stores as the result of the procedure. **THAT'S** the object-like thing Stata works with. R would return the test results in the `fisher.test()$p.value` component, and Stata creates returned values, `r(component)` for simple commands and `e(component)` for estimation commands.

If you want a loop solution (if you have many sets), you can do this:

```
   forvalues k=1/2 {
    tabulate x y [fw=f`k'], exact
    generate p`k' = r(p_exact)
   }
```

That's the scripting capacity in which Stata, IMHO, is way stronger than R (although it can be argued that this is an extremely dirty programming trick). The local macro `k` takes values from 1 to 2, and this macro is substituted as ``k'` everywhere in the curly bracketed piece of code.

Alternatively, you can keep the results in Stata short term memory as scalars:

```
    tabulate x y [fw=f1], exact
    scalar p1 = r(p_exact)
    tabulate x y [fw=f2], exact
    scalar p2 = r(p_exact)
```

However, the scalars are not associated with the data set, so you cannot save them with the 
data.

The immediate commands like `cci` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938624/perform-fisher-exact-test-from-aggregrated-using-stata/6939863#6939863) would also have returned values that you can similarly retrieve.

HTH, Stas

Answer (score 2):

Have a look the `cci` command with the `exact` option:

```
cci 10 15 30 10, exact
```

It is part of the so-called "immediate" commands. They allow you to do computations directly from the arguments rather than from data stored in memory. Have a look at `help immediate`

Answer (score 0):

Each observation in the poster's original question apparently consisted of the four counts in one traditional 2 x 2 table. Stas's code applied to data of individual observations. Nick pointed out that -cci- can analyze a b c d data. Here's code that applies -cci to each table and, like Stas's code, adds the p-values to the data set. The `` forvalues i = 1/`=_N' `` statement tells Stata to run the loop from the first to the last observation. `` a[`i'] `` refers to the the value of the variable `a' in the i-th observation.

```
    clear
    input a b c d
    10 2 8 4
    5 8 2 1
    end

    gen exactp1 = .
    gen exactp2 =.
    label var exactp1 "1-sided exact p"
    label var exactp2 "2-sided exact p"
    forvalues i = 1/`=_N'{
      local a = a[`i']
      local b = b[`i']
      local c = c[`i']
      local d = d[`i']
      qui cci `a' `b' `c' `d', exact
      replace exactp1 = r(p1_exact) in `i'
      replace exactp2 = r(p_exact) in `i'
      }
    list
```

Note that there is no problem in giving a local macro the same name as a variable.